# How to transfer ETH between 2 ETH addresses using GETH (without keystore/JSON file)

Tags: go-ethereum

I have 2 ETH addresses (P and N) and a ETH Node (synchronized and running 24h with GETH client).
I do not have ETH on the node address (address N)
I do have ETH on my address P.
Need transfer from address P into address N using private key of address P.
I want to use my Terminal command line on my machine running GETH to transfer ETH from address P to address N.
How to do it?

P.S. without using MIST or MyEtherWallet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geth doesn't like to work with private keys directly, but if you put the private key in a file and then do `geth account import <filename>`, you'll then have the account visible in geth.

Then you can run `geth attach`, unlock the account via `web3.personal.unlockAccount(...)`, and finally `web3.eth.sendTransaction(...)` from it.